# Creating new compose activity in my existing project am getting build issue

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

> Caused by: [style/AppTheme.NoActionBar]
> C:\Users\Hp\StudioProjects\robin\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
> [style/AppTheme.NoActionBar]
> C:\Users\Hp\StudioProjects\robin\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml:
> Error: Duplicate resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is because of "style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" already present in
   your existing project under **styles.xml**.
2. You need to check for the **themes.xml** file under the resources.
3. This **themes.xml** file is created by default when you create an empty compose activity.
4. Deleting this **themes.xml** will sort out the issue.